# Regex negative lookahead in python

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I need to look for all the instances of 'carbon' in the texts which is not followed by 'dioxide'.
So, in the sentence '...twice as much **carbon dioxide** as the poorer half of the world from 1990 to 2015, according to new research on **carbon emissions**' I'd like to catch the 2nd instance of carbon and not the 1st one.

```
carbon(?!dioxide)
```

doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: `carbon(?! dioxide)`?

Comment: Try: `\bcarbon\b(?!\s*dioxide)`